# Why HTMLAudio sources do not appear in Dev Tool Network Tab after page load?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, html5-audio

Say I want to play some audio on my webpage.

I would do this in JavaScript:

```
let snd = new Audio('/horn.mp3');
snd.play();
```

However, when I look in the Network Tab, even after clearing cache, I don't see the request for the mp3 file.